# Giving client side validation in ASP.Net MVC using Razor ViewEngine in View(.cshtml page)

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to give client side validations for registration form in View anyhow using javascript, jQuery, or other ways to give validations client side.

And I am using strongly typed model.

my view contains code like this..

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserName)

                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.UserName)

            <input type="submit" value="Create" id="submit" />
}
```

Please give solution for this...Thanks

Comment: You also will need `@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserName)`.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use jQuery and jQuery Validator. Next you need to look into using DataAnnotations in your Model and mark what properties are required in your model.

See the following for a good example of setting up client side validation

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/718004/ASP-NET-MVC-Client-Side-Validation

Comment: Thanks Gjohn, is it possible to give validations without having to change in Model?

Comment: You can just use jQuery Validator for that but that will be strictly client side validation. If that is all you need then look at the jQuery Validator plugin there are plenty of examples on how to set it up for your project. http://jqueryvalidation.org